# In windows how to dump all resources a process uses in C?

Tags: c, windows

It seems some software can do this, how is it done?

Comment: When you say resources do you mean the ones you'd get from say a resource editor?

Answer (score 0):

[GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will give you lots of information on the resources a process uses in Windows.